# Shutting down an ExecutorService from running task

Tags: java, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm using a single threaded `ScheduledExecutorService` in order to process some `Runnable` tasks. When my `Runnable` has finished its work, it reschedules itself in the `ScheduledExecutorService` with a variable delay. This happens indefinitely until the `Runnable` catches an `Exception`.

```
public class Runner { 

    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    public void startWorking() { 
        // Single-shot start
        service.submit(new Task(service));
    }

    public void stopWorking() { 
        service.shutDown();
        // Do some other stuff
    }

    private static final class Task implements Runnable { 
        ScheduledExecutorService service;
        private Task(ScheduledExecutorService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }
        @Override 
        public void run() { 
            try { 
                // Do some work...
                service.schedule(this, variableDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
            catch(SomethingHappenedException e){ 
                // Shutdown service
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Can I `shutdown()` or `shutdownNow()` the `ExecutorService` safely from `Task.run()`? Something doesn't look right if the thread will be provoking an interrupt to itself.

When an exception is caught while executing `Task`, I'd like to `shutdown` the `service`, ideally calling `Runner.stopWorking()`.

I know I could use a `Callable` instead and let `Runner` manage reschedulings, but I'd like to keep this structure (`Runner` will have more analogous `service`s, so an infinite loop just doesn't look right there).

I guess I could subclass `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to override `afterExecute` and handle shutdown there, using a reference to `Runner`.

```
public class Runner { 
    ScheduledExecutorService service = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1){
      protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { 
        if (t != null) { 
            Runner.this.stopWorking();
        }
    };
    // ...
}
```

My concern with this approach is, if `afterExecute` will be invoked by the thread that ran the `Task`, this would have the same effects as calling `shutDown()` from `Task.run()` itself.

Is there any other alternative approach to this?

Comment: Looks like calling `shutdown()` or even `shutdownNow()` from the task itself is safe, and works properly. If it really is, the answer to this question is trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I shutdown() or shutdownNow() the ExecutorService safely from
>   Task.run()? Something doesn't look right if the thread will be
>   provoking an interrupt to itself.

`shutdown()` will not interrupt already running tasks but will prevent new task from beeing submited.
`shutdownNow()` doesn't interrupt running tasks either, but "signals" all workers that they should be terminated. It is up to `Thread` implementation (or rather `Runnable` itself) will it honor such signal (`Thread.isTerminated()` as I remember) or not.

And yes, it is perfectly fine for thread to signal itself to be terminated. So it is safe to `shutdown()` executor from running task.